# How to programmatically disable Program Compatibility Assistant in Windows 7 and Vista for a native C++ application?

Tags: visual-c++, compatibility

I have a custom installer application built with C++/ATL. The application's target platform is XP3, VS solution consists of static lib and exe projects. The application always to be started elevated, i.e. as Administrator

When I run it from Visual Studio (VS itself is started as Administrator) then everything is fine, PCA is never shown. When I run it on the same machine from Explorer then PCA is also never shown.

However, when I run it on a fresh Windows 7 machine then PCA is always shown, no matter if I start it from elevated or non-elevated Explorer.

Manifest-related section in project properties is set like this: http://screencast.com/t/70GOcbf243

What do I do in order to get rid of PCA on the second machine?
Thank you!

Comment: Work down [the list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh994464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should rename your application. There are some hard-coded names which forces the PCA... like:

- Productname contains “*instal*” or “*setup*” or “*update*”
- Companyname contains “*instal*” or “*setup*” or “*update*”
- Internalname contains “*instal*” and app is not named “TrustedInstaller.exe”
- Originalfilename contains “*instal*” and app is not named “TrustedInstaller.exe”
- Filedescription contains “*instal*” and app is not named “TrustedInstaller.exe”
- Filename contains “*instal*” and is not named “TrustedInstaller.exe”
- Exportname contains “setup.exe” or “install.exe” or “stub32″ or “stub32.exe” or “signstub.exe”
- Filename contains “*patch*” or “*setup*” or “*uninst*” or “*update*” or “lhaca*.exe”
- Filedescription contains “*instal*” or “*setup*” or “*update*” or “*uninst*”
- Originalfilename contains “*setup*” or “*update*”
- Originalfilename contains “*setup*” or “*update*”

See also: [Custom installer without warning dialog… (TrustedInstaller.exe)](http://blog.kalmbach-software.de/2009/06/09/custom-installer-without-warning-dialog-trustedinstallerexe/)

As an alternativ, you can add the OS compatibility section in your application manifest to prevent the PCA. Ad the following to your application manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
    <application> 
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista --> 
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 --> 
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/> 
    </application> 
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

For more info, see also [Application Manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371711)

Comment: That was it, my installer contained "instal" in originalfilename, so once it is changed PCA does not show up anymore. However, as a part of the package I have the third application that also have "instal" everywhere: in name, original name, etc and yet PCA does not appear neither on dev nor on fresh machine...

Comment: You should also add an VIsta/Win7 Manifest: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2009/03/27/manifesting-for-compatibility-on-windows-7.aspx