# Is there any way to set OS compatibility to windows application programmatically or bitrock install builder?

Tags: c++, windows, bitrock

I am trying to setup windows application compatibility to where ever it installing(either it can be windows 7/8/10). This should be done before installation. If it can be done through any installation setup also fine. Just to inform, I am using bitrock setup for creating installer.

I have tried some links([How to programmatically disable Program Compatibility Assistant in Windows 7 and Vista for a native C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660404/how-to-programmatically-disable-program-compatibility-assistant-in-windows-7-and)), but not able get any option programmatically or through bitrock installation setup.

unfortunately I don't have any code so far.

I expect compatibility should be set to compiled executable where ever I am  installing.

Comment: The manifest is a resource and you can update your executable on demand. That would break digital signatures though.

Comment: so, can't we do this with out breaking digital signature. Because signing is necessary for my executable.

Comment: You can sign again after updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I managed to set the compatibility through

```
reg.exe Add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "C:\Program Files\MyApp\Test.exe" /d "WIN7RTM"
```

Have executed this command from a batch script and attached to bitrock XML file.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/379375/how-can-i-set-the-compatibility-mode-for-an-executable-from-the-command-line .