# ClickOnce Execute abnormalities

Tags: vb.net, windows-7, clickonce

client os : windows 7

My WPF application release use ClickOnce，sometimes , start application in client, can not show application UI, but can find this application is run in task manager

Set compatibility mode for windows xp , Can solve this problem

Each time it is released, it must be set up once

Is there any way to effectively solve this problem?

this is my setting

[image]

Comment: Windows 7 is no longer supported. Upgrade to a supported operating system.

Comment: I also hope to do so, but I can't

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57426690/is-there-any-way-to-set-os-compatibility-to-windows-application-programmatically

Comment: This is a good idea, but how to start CMD after downloading new applications and before starting the application?